# Исходники компонентов

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуй ХэшКод! Скажите реально ли, и **как** посмотреть исходники, например, компонента button, что такое кнопка? Как она устроена и пр. А то, к примеру, есть интересные задумки, как, например, написать свою кнопку, которая будет почти как стандартная, но чуть-чуть изменена **внутри**. Да и вопрос, как вообще начать писать свои компоненты? Очень интересная тема!!! К примеру, очень хочу написать компонент "браузер", но понятия не имею даже, с чего начинать...

Comment: Это ж MS,  а не OpenSource. Всё коммерческая тайна.

Comment: Гуглите в сторону Reflector, ещё подобная вещь была у jetBrains, но не помню название

Comment: @karmadro4, здорово! А как вообще (только своими словами) такие штучки делаются?

Comment: avp, ничего не понял, какие именно штучки?

Comment: Ну, при клике на URL в Вашем комментарии открывается окошко (после анимации) с результатами поиска.

Comment: @avp, а, дык это ж [Let Me Google That For You][http://lmgtfy.com/] с намёком, что первый же результат обсуждает и частичный реверс и совместимые сырцы.

Comment: @karmadro4, упиваемся своей начитанностью ? Какие буковки писать в комментарии/ответе, чтобы URL таким образом работал объяснить влом ?

Comment: @avp, заходите на http://lmgtfy.com/
генерите сообщение, потом копируете получившийся URL

Comment: @Olter, понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

[Reflector](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP) (платный), [IlSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) (удобный и бесплатный) или [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP).

Так же в состав [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) входит очень удобная утилита для просмотра кода системных сборок.
Просто открой сборки и посмотри исходники. Правда, надеяться на то что там будет все просто и понятно - очень наивно

Answer (score 1):

Также исходники **.NET**'а и некоторых его компонентов доступны для скачивания с сайта [microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).